# Unable to apply Collectors.groupingBy on an IntStream

Tags: java, java-stream

This code works fine with other objects, but not int, even though those are autoboxed to Integer. I am unable to understand the error message.

```
jshell> String[] names = new String[]{"apple", "apple", "banana"};
names ==> String[3] { "apple", "apple", "banana" }

jshell> Map<String, Integer> stringMap = Arrays.stream(names).collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.summingInt(e -> 1)));
stringMap ==> {banana=1, apple=2}

jshell> int[] nums = new int[]{1,2,3,3,4};
nums ==> int[5] { 1, 2, 3, 3, 4 }

jshell> Map<Integer, Integer> numsMap = Arrays.stream(nums).collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.summingInt(e -> 1)));
|  Error:
|  method collect in interface java.util.stream.IntStream cannot be applied to given types;
|    required: java.util.function.Supplier<R>,java.util.function.ObjIntConsumer<R>,java.util.function.BiConsumer<R,R>
|    found: java.util.stream.Collector<java.lang.Object,capture#1 of ?,java.util.Map<java.lang.Object,java.lang.Integer>>
|    reason: cannot infer type-variable(s) R
|      (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
|  Map<Integer, Integer> numsMap = Arrays.stream(nums).collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.summingInt(e -> 1)));
|                                  ^-------------------------^
```

Comment: `IntStream` doesn't have `collect(Collector)` method like `Stream`. Consider using `Integer[]` instead of `int[]`, or call `.boxed()` first to convert `IntStream` to `Stream<Integerr>`.

Comment: Anyway what do you mean by "..even though those are autoboxed to Integer"?

Comment: Side note: instead of `Collectors.summingInt(e -> 1)` you can use `Collectors.counting()`. It produces a `Map<…, Long>` though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### tl;dr

Add a call to `.boxed`.

### No auto-boxing here

As [Commented by Pshemo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77376912/unable-to-apply-collectors-groupingby-on-an-intstream/77377051#comment136410810_77376912), [`IntStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api//java.base/java/util/stream/IntStream.html) does not [auto-box](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boxing_(computer_science)#Autoboxing). You are working with `int` primitives only in an `IntStream`.

Your code would work if you simply  insert a call to [`IntStream#boxed`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api//java.base/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#boxed()). Your stream of `int` primitive values then becomes a stream of [`Integer`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api//java.base/java/lang/Integer.html) objects.

```java
int[] ints = new int[] { 1 , 2 , 3 , 3 , 4 };
Map < Integer , Integer > integersMap =
        Arrays
                .stream ( ints )
                .boxed ( )  // ⬅️
                .collect (
                        Collectors.groupingBy (
                                Function.identity ( ) ,
                                Collectors.summingInt ( ( Integer i ) -> 1 )
                        )
                );
```

> stringMap = {banana=1, apple=2}

And, for reference, the `String` code.

```java
String[] names = new String[] { "apple" , "apple" , "banana" };
Map < String , Integer > stringMap =
        Arrays
                .stream ( names )
                .collect (
                        Collectors.groupingBy (
                                Function.identity ( ) ,
                                Collectors.summingInt ( ( String s ) -> 1 )
                        )
                );
```

> integersMap = {1=1, 2=1, 3=2, 4=1}